# Force text on last line of page when there is a table on next page

Tags: align, line-breaking, wrap

I am writing a document in overleaf (latex). I have a 2-column paper. There is a table inserted on the next page. The problem is that the last line on the previous page before the table is a blank line. I want the content to appear on this last line instead of leaving it blank. In the attached image.. see the line after 'ultrasound sensors is provided by'

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Using the package `lipsum` you can replace your text with dummy text    with some like `\lipsum[1-6]\lipsum[7][1-19]` to make easily that MWE.

Comment: In the past I used the command line `\vfill\eject` to jump from one column to a new one while maintaining alignment in the columns. The `\vfill` adds space (empty lines) to the first column. The `\eject` puts the next line in a new column.